# Rollup of all Tasks of a Recurring Meeting in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, view, task

We have set up a SharePoint meeting workspace (using WSS 3.0) for our weekly team meeting. As part of our process we will enter tasks and assign them to individuals during the meeting.

Unfortunately the task lists are specific to a particular meeting. We are looking for a way to roll up all of the task generated during our weekly meeting into a unified view. Is there a way to create a view using CAML that will do that?

I know we could use a separate task list outside of the meeting workspace, but then we'd loose the meeting context the task was generated in.

A WSS 3.0 solution would be preferred!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all it is is one list in recurring meeting, then you can press Actions -> Show List Items From All Meetings (something like that).

If you want to aggregate multiple meetings and/or lists ->

- For MOSS, you could use Content Query
  Web Part, but you would have to do
  some formatting and other stuff to
  have it display it more like a
  list-view. Artricle on how-to
  [here](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx).
- You may use [SPDataSource and Rollups
  with the Data View](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx)
- Programmatically, for MOSS and WSS,
  you could use SPGridView object for
  SPSiteDataQuery query results.
  SPSiteDataQuery ([examples](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/02/27/spsitedataquery-samples-for-wss-v3.aspx)) can
  query all list items based on list
  template.
- There is also an option to do Linked
  Source in SharePoint Designer, but I
  would not recommend that as it is not
  dynamic (well, you have to type list
  urls manually every time you add new
  list somwhere). If someone is
  interested see [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx).

For a regular SPQuery on recurring meetings, you have to set [SPQuery.MeetingInstanceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.meetinginstanceid.aspx) to [SPMeeting.SpecialInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.meetings.spmeeting.specialinstance.aspx) or other value to either query a specific meeting or all meeting items.

Comment: Thanks, these are good suggestions!

Unfortunately, the first one (CQWP) is a MOSS-only solution (there are some suggestions on how to make it work on WSS 3.0 but I haven't been successful in implementing them). I failed to mention in my question that we are using WSS 3.0 at this time.

I'll check out the code-based solutions in the next couple of days.

Comment: Well, you are welcome to use DataView in SharePoint Designer, if you don't want to fire up Visual Studio :)